# how to hit server using ajax with post method

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

Here is my html code

```
          function loadDoc(){
 var num = '{"empid": 45,"name": "gaurav","salary":566.55}';
  $.ajax({

url: 'http://localhost:9029/addS',
method: 'POST',
data: num,
success: function(response){
      console.log("response::::"+response);
      $("#output").text(response);
},

error: function( jqXHR,textStatus, errorThrown){

    console.log("Error askdjk");
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
}

  });   
}
```

Below is my java code

```
     @RequestMapping(value="/addS",method={RequestMethod.POST})

     public String addEmployee(@RequestParam int empid,@RequestParam String name,@RequestParam double salary){

    return "employee added successfully(Separate): "+name;
}
```

M getting error 400 ...i tried many thing but not able to solve the problem .....

Comment: Problem solved .............i have added ...addEmployee(@RequestBody Map map)  ...thx every one for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a object for request body, such as:

```
public class Num{
 public int empid,
 public String name,
 public double salary
}
```

Then you need a `@RequestBody`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addS",method={RequestMethod.POST})

public String addEmployee(@RequestBody Num num){

    return "employee added successfully(Separate): "+num.name;
}
```

Or change your ajax code to GET.

Comment: now m getting 415 error ...with above Num class method

Comment: @gauravsingh Can you give me the request's detail?

Comment: hmm.... your solution is working i was not sending as object that why i was getting 415(media not supported ) now m sending as a Object...show its working

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `data: JSON.stringify(num)` instead of `data: num` in your ajax request.

Comment: yes....  same 400 error even with  JSON.stringify(num)